# How do I escape Java generics in Gmaven?

Tags: java, groovy, diamond-operator, gmaven

So you are writing a groovy script with some Java in it in GMaven. In between the source tags:

```
<source>

...some groovy code here

List<Chicken> = new ArrayList<>()

...some more groovy code here

</source>
```

Problem the < and the > look like XML tag components. Is there a way to escape those and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can escape them with XML/HTML entities

```
List&lt;Chicken&gt; = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;()
```

***Reference** :*
[List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: Both this solution and the other solution work. I prefer the other solution (using CDATA) but this one answers the question as stated.

Answer (score 3):

Nest the code in CDATA.

Check out this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp